# Pasar información de xml a una tabla creada en oracle con sqldeveloper

Tags: sql, xml, oracle-11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

queria ver si me ayudan con un problema que estoy teniendo, lo que pasa es que tengo un archivo de xml y lo quiero pasar a una tabla que cree en oracle sql developer, la verdad no tengo idea de como empezar y hacerlo?

Comaparto un fragmento de mi xml, lo pongo en una foto, espero y me pueda dar a entender:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y aqui pongo la estructura de mi tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quedo al pendiente de sus comentarios.

Saludos y excelente tarde

Comment: Sería ideal que compartieras un poco más de detalle del problema como: estructura de la tabla que aceptará el documento XML (una alternativa es utilizar un campo de tipo CLOB). ¿Desde dónde vas a enviar a guardar el archivo? ¿Qué tipo de aplicación es? ¿Cómo vas a explotarla? , etc.

Comment: Hola, El archivo xml ya lo tengo, de echo lo quise compartir por aqui pero está emuy largo veré la forma en editarlo y poner la estructura de la tabla, en unos minutos actualizo mi pregunta, saludos

Comment: Hola, ya edtité mi pregunta, espero y me pueda dar entender, saludos

Answer (score 1):

Ahora queda claro que quieres importar los datos desde un archivo XML a una tabla. Para efectuar esto, es necesario que el archivo se encuentre en el mismo server (File System) en que está ejecutandose el motor de Oracle. A grandes rasgos esto es lo que tendrías que hacer:

1. Almacenar el archivo XML en una ruta del sistema de archivos del servidor Oracle.
2. Crear un objeto Directory en Oracle para poder referenciar a la ruta en que se encuentra almacenado el archivo.
3. Para poder acceder al contenido del archivo XML se debe utilizar dos funciones de Oracle: BFILENAME (permite recuperar el contenido de un archivo desde un directorio), y XMLType(te permite acceder al documento XML y manipular el contenido del mismo)...
   El detalle lo puedes encontrar en la documentación de Oracle (en inglés) (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/appdev.920/a96620/xdb04cre.htm)...

Por acá hay un buen artículo con información que puede ser de utilidad (también en inglés)

https://slobaray.com/2013/03/04/loading-xml-file-into-oracle-tables/

Ahora bien, por las imágenes que compartes, veo que se trata de datos extraidos desde un SQL Server. Si tuvieras acceso a dicho server, podías analizar la alternativa de enviar la información directo a Oracle utilizando SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS) o algún otro ETL.

Espero la información te sea de utilidad....